# How to pass arguments to a web app running on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I'd like to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  if(args[0].equals("debugMode")){
    //do some debug mode stuff
  }
  else {
    //do some production mode stuff
  }
}
```

But this is a web application running on tomcat, so there is no main method in my application and no args variable I can tap in to.

I'm using Eclipse and I know that I can set Program Arguments and VM arguments, I just don't know how to access them from code.

Comment: one thing you could do is to create and read in a properties file

Comment: You can send system properties to your server's JVM. Try editing your launch configuration and add JVM arguments such as `-Dmyproperty=myValue` and read it in your program by calling `System.getProperty("myproperty")`

Comment: That's it! I'd tried doing that, except when I called getProperty I forgot to pull out the D.

Comment: I actually have a properties file but I'd like to be able to run my application on my local machine in debug mode, then deploy it and have it automatically switch to production mode. I always forget to change the properties file.

Comment: If you always forget to do things, you're right to automate them. However, the question for "passing arguments" makes this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and the suggested properties (files or parameters) would be one solution to it. Read a properties file from a standard location (or system property) in the appserver - have some values in there in your dev system,  other values in your production server. And if you're really strict: Have your app refuse to work if it can determine neither of them, with a helpful error message.